# Unable to find conda binary with reticulate - use_python path issue

Tags: python, r, rstudio, conda, reticulate

I am trying to use reticulate in R studio.  I have several python options, but when running
`use_python("/opt/conda/bin/python3", required = TRUE)` conda still cannot be found using the below functions.  I'm pasting my python path options below.  Any suggestions?

```
reticulate::conda_list()
reticulate::conda_python()
reticulate::conda_version()
```

The above functions cannot find conda.
Error: Unable to find conda binary. Is Anaconda installed?

Using `py_config()` I notice I have several python options - but when specifying these I cannot initiate python.

```
use_python("/opt/conda/bin/python3", required = TRUE)
use_condaenv(conda = "/opt/conda/bin/python3", required = TRUE)


python:         /opt/conda/bin/python
libpython:      /opt/conda/lib/libpython3.8.so
pythonhome:     /opt/conda:/opt/conda
version:        3.8.5 (default, Sep  4 2020, 07:30:14)  [GCC 7.3.0]
numpy:          /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy
numpy_version:  1.19.5
os:             /opt/conda/lib/python3.8

python versions found: 
 /opt/conda/bin/python
 /usr/bin/python3
 /opt/conda/bin/python3
 /usr/bin/python
 /usr/local/bin/python
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code doesn't work lies in the wrong specification.

For `use_python`, the path must point to the python executable of the conda environment, which looks like `/opt/conda/envs/<env_name>/bin/python`. Important is that it contains the folder `envs`.

For `use_condaenv`, the documentation specifies about its arguments:

```
condaenv    
The name of the Conda environment to use.

conda   
The path to a conda executable. By default, reticulate will check the PATH, as well as other standard locations for Anaconda installations.
```

So for condaenv, you specify the name of your conda environment, e.g. "reticulate".
For conda, you specify the path of the conda executable, which you find easily by opening a terminal and typing `which conda`. This gives me e.g. `miniforge3/condabin/conda` (for M1 apple silicon).

In your case, it would probably look like:

```
use_condaenv(conda = "/opt/conda/bin/conda", condaenv = "<env_name>")
```